# Select particular value from the data set in R

Tags: r, select

I have a set of data (x1, x2, x3.....). From that, I need to select that particular data which is just below given data, say (X) in R
The following sample and code give the value of X as 44.75. I need to write a select code that will select 43 from the dataset.

```
sample <- c(20,25,30,24,27,33,18,26,43, 57)
a <- (quantile(sample, 0.75))
b <- (quantile(sample, 0.25))
X <- a + 1.5*(a-b)
select <-
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `==` with `numeric` works fine when the numbers do not have high precision ([R FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f) and [Why are these numbers not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518/3358272)), so the other answer may suffice, but here are some options that are more robust in that way:

```r
sort(sample[sample < X], decreasing = TRUE)[1]
# [1] 43

tmp <- sample[sample < X]
tmp[which.min(abs(tmp - X))]
# [1] 43
```

Comment: Thanks. It works my problem.